# How to calculate Bit Flag in javascript?

Tags: javascript, bitflags

im writing a free tool for SEO... implementing an api from seomoz and the flags look like this

```
URL Metric,Bit Flag
Title,1
URL,4
Subdomain,8
Root Domain,16
External Links,32
Links,2048
mozRank,16384
mozTrust,131072
```

these are just a few but i dont know how to calculate the proper bit flag in javascript... is it just an OR of all the integers of the flags i want to use? a small snippet to show me how to make a var that holds some of these flags would be awesome...

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is it just an OR of all the integers of the flags i want to use?

Yes. `Title|URL|Links` (etc.) would be `1|4|2048`

Answer (score 6):

Just like in C:

```
var flags = 0;
// *snip*
flags |= MyFlag;
flags |= MyOtherFlag;
// *snip*
if ((flags & MyFlag) == MyFlag)
{
    // do stuff
}
```